# How do I get Garrison Resources

Tags: world-of-warcraft

With the Garrison being introduced to World of WarCraft, we all want to make our own Garrison prosper and expand into our own little home town.

In order to make the Garrison grow, we need to collect Garrison Resources.

**How can you obtain Garrison Resources?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend using the [following guide](http://www.icy-veins.com/wow/garrison-complete-guide) (I'm actually using it myself).

According to their information :

> Garrison Resources are earned from:
>
> - the Garrison Cache, which is an object located next to your Town Hall that you unlock during the introductory quest line in your starting zone and that generates 1x Garrison Resource every 10 minutes (up to a maximum of 500);
> - the Lumber Mill, where Work Orders can generate up to 120x Garrison Resources per day;
> - the Trading Post, where Work Orders can generate up to 120x Garrison Resources per day;
> - completing quests in your Garrison (but they are not usually repeatable);
>     killing named mobs in Draenor.

There are hidden chests too, hidden everywhere in Draenor that contain resources. You can use TomTom (a gps like add-on) and Paste (an add-on to enter big commands for TomTom at once) to find them easily. You can use the [following list](http://www.ownedcore.com/forums/world-of-warcraft/world-of-warcraft-guides/500503-treasure-rare-spawn-locations-wod.html) of commands to add the corresponding waypoints to your TomTom.

Comment: Sending followers on their quests can reward garrison resources also. The Stables have daily quests which reward resources (not sure if that is always the reward though). In short, there are many ways, but what Shunwoo has posted are probably the best.